# Указатель в срезе

Tags: golang

Есть 2 варианта объявления среза:

1. `list := make([]*Person, 5)`
2. `list := make([]Person, 5)`

Как себя поведёт 2' вариант при передаче среза в методы/функции? 
Будет ли оверхед, по причине того что в срезе объекты, а не указатели (будут копии персон каждый раз при передаче)? 
Или т.к. у нас срез всё равно содержимое будет передаваться по ссылке ?

Answer (score 1):

Слайс/срез - это всегда структура из трёх машинных слов (указатель, длина/length, вместительность/capacity). Вне зависимости от того, какие элементы внутри.

*Массив* передался бы по значению. `list := [5]Person{}` передаст `5 * sizeof(Person)` байт.

Comment: Я спрашивал не про массив/срез. А как поведёт себя содержимое среза, если там не указатели, а значение. Будут ли копии содержимого среза при каждом вызове метода/функции ?

Comment: Я и ответил, что копии не будет, так как срез всегда "передаётся по ссылке".